# Non-Linear modelling in R

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression

I have a dataset which contains Retention (DV) and Customer Satisfaction data (IV, 7 variables, scale 1-10) for 55000 observations. Now I want to know which increase in number has the biggest impact on retention. > e.g. In the Netherlands it's likely to assume that the difference between a 5 (insufficient) and 6 (sufficient) is bigger than the differences between a 4 and a 5. Which statistical test suits this problem the best? I found several options, but i'm always open for more suggestions.

- non-linear modelling
- generalized additive models
- permutational anova
- ordinal regression (probit regression)
- Logit or probit regression
- Generalized Linear/nonlinear Model (GLZ)

Example of the data:

```
df <- data.frame("Retention" = c(0,1,1,1,0,1), "Q1" = c(6,10,9,7,6,NA), "Q2" = c(10, 10, 10,10,10,10), "Q3" = c(9,10,9,9,NA,10))
```

So in short: I want to measure the impact of satisfaction on retention per level increase and per IV

Comment: Which methods will be appropriate will depend upon the nature of your dependent variable.  In your sample data, the DV has values of either 0, 1, or 2.  Is this variable a continuous measured variable, an ordinal variable, or a categorical variable?

Comment: @Sal Mangiafico:The DV can either be 0 (churn) or 1 (retention), thus a binary variable. The IVs are on a 1-10 scale

Comment: Since your DV is binomial, a logical choice would be to use logistic regression.  This is a form of generalized linear model.  There may be other options, like using a GAM with a binomial link function (mgcv package).  But it seems like another issue you are concerned about is that your IV's  are ordinal in nature.  One option would be to analyze each question separately, and use a test of association appropriate for ordinal data like Cochran-Armitage.  Another option is to treat the ordinal data as interval.

Comment: Do you mean that i can see the 'effect' of a score increase with a logistic regression using the >exp(df$coefficients) option? I believe I cannot only interpret the coefficients of significant variables

Comment: When you relate retention as function of satisfaction (e.g. by means of logistic regression as suggested above), then you should realize that this is not *exactly* the same as analyzing the effect of increasing satisfaction. The underlying assumption (which I believe is fine but should be noted) is that when you change something, to get more satisfaction with your customers, then you can still use the same retention vs satisfaction curve. Be aware that you only measured satisfaction and retention at a specific situation which is not same as measuring effects on people that changed satisfaction

Comment: @MelvinBredewold , yes, you could use the coefficients from the regression to interpret the effect of the IVs on the DV.  Whether you look at all the coefficients or just the significant ones may depend on your purposes, but looking at only the significant terms will keep things simple.  In any case, I would start with looking at some summary statistics.  For example, you could calculate the proportion of retention for each level of each question.  Looking at that this data in either tables or plots will help you understand what's going on with the data.

Comment: @Martijn Weterings, would it maybe be better to adjust the 1-10 scale into dummy variables? In that case I can maybe analyze which increase has a bigger impact (having ''1'' as my base level and 9 other dummies)? I understand that it will not be the same as changing satisfaction indeed, it are specifiek numbers at specifiek situations, thanks!

Comment: @Melvin, that is *one* way of doing it. The dependency on each of your seven variables could be analyses by some model, but indeed much easier is to treat them as categorical variables and any possible of shape of model is possible..... Yet, there are many more aspects that are involved in the analysis of your data. (1) it is multivariate and it may be difficult to find for each separate variable the point at which the incline of retention is largest  (2) Possibly much easier would be to see first if you get clusters in your data, and whether the retention is different for the clusters....

Comment: .... see this example of a logistic regression analysis done with the iris dataset http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/230133_fb9cb3c35ca345d0b9e5726ed3f45a21.html See that there is a strong clustering (which you can only see in a multivariate representation and not so much in a one-dimensional view). It isn't homogeneous, and it's questionable if a focus on satisfaction shift also causes a cluster shift, and instead won't just mean (mostly) that the groups/clusters will change in their satisfaction, but not so much their retention behavior (the causation is weakly proven by this data)